# Passing onclick handler as part of dynamic HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

I came across similar questions, but it did not have the exact problem/solution I was hoping for. I apologize in advance if this has been answered before and I missed it.

I have dynamic HTML code that I insert on AJAX return from db:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.Links.length;i++){  
  $('#vid-list').append('<li class="vid-item" onclick="startVideo(\''+data.Links[i]+'\')"><div class="thumb"><img src="'+ data.Thumb[i]+'"></div><div class="desc">'+data.Name[i]+'</div></li>');
  }
```

data.links is an array of youtube embed links. data.Name is an array of titles, data.thumb is the respective thumbnail images and so on.

startVideo is a fucntion in my JS file defined as this:

```
$(function(){
   function startVideo(srcUrl){
      $('#popup2').style.display ='block';
      document.getElementById('vid_frame').src=srcUrl;
    }
 });
```

It passes the link from the dynamic HTML to play the video in an iframe popup. The HTML code for that is :

```
<div class="vid-list-container">
                    <ul id="vid-list">
                        <!--need to insert videos here-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

```
 <div id="popup2" class="popup">
        <iframe id="vid_frame" frameborder="0" height="315" src="" width="560" allowscriptaccess="always">
            </iframe>
        <a class="close" href="#" onclick="toggleVideo('hide')">
        <img id="close-icon" src="../images/info-close-icon.png"></a></div>
    </div>
```

So this is my problem: The HTML looks fine after loading. Data gets properly populated within the HTML elements.

But when I click on the video, no popup appears. i.e. startVideo() does not get called onClick event. This code worked fine with static HTML code. I read other questions and it was said that if the event happens after the dynamic element has completely loaded, there should not be problem with the binding.But that is not the case here.

Are there any other checks that I could do?

Comment: try removing **$(function(){** from the function

Comment: You're getting confused with dynamic elements needing event delegation.  There is no "binding" because you're using `onclick=` attribute, so not binding an event handler via js.

Comment: The issue is scope - `startVideo` is scoped inside the jquery startup function, so can't be called from outside this.  As @Roy says, move it *outside* the `$(function(){});` code

Comment: Thank you so much!  Works perfectly. I can't believe I didn't try that. Make a lot of sense